# How target DOM with next.js useRef in map

Tags: reactjs, next.js

```
// next.js code 
export default function Header() {
  const pp = useRef(null);
  const pp2 = useRef(null);

  function show() {
    pp.current.classList.add("right-0");
    pp.current.classList.remove("-right-2/3");
    pp2.current.classList.add("animation")
  }
  function close() {
    pp.current.classList.remove("right-0");
    pp.current.classList.add("-right-2/3");
  }
  let pagename: string = usePathname();
  let ll = links.map((e, i) => {
    return (
      <Link 
        ref={pp2}
        className="font-bold text-2xl hover:opacity-50"
        key={e.name}
        href={e.href}
      >
        {e.name}
      </Link>
    );  
});
```

this navbar i can't upload all code but i am using tailwind on my project, the problem here when i click on hamburger icon call show function and animation only work on the last link element

```
// css code
.animation {
  animation-name: shop-animation;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 0.1s;
}
@keyframes shop-animation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(0px, 10px);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

this css animation no more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this one `pp2` ref that you are passing to all links in your `map`, hence at the end, the last one only is in `pp2`. You could use use an array `ref`, like so:

```
export default function Header() {
  const pp = useRef(null);
  const pp2 = useRef([]);

  function show() {
    pp.current.classList.add("right-0");
    pp.current.classList.remove("-right-2/3");
    pp2.current.forEach((e) => {
      e.classList.add("animation");
    });
  }
  function close() {
    pp.current.classList.remove("right-0");
    pp.current.classList.add("-right-2/3");
  }
  let pagename: string = usePathname();
  let ll = links.map((e, i) => {
    return (
      <Link
        ref={(el) => {
          pp2.current[i] = el;
        }}
        className="font-bold text-2xl hover:opacity-50"
        key={e.name}
        href={e.href}
      >
        {e.name}
      </Link>
    );
  });
```